# finding accessors of userdefined class at runtime

Tags: java

```
public class Emp {

    private String employeeId;
    private String employeeName;
    private double employeeSalary;

    public String getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }
    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return employeeName;
    }
    public double getEmployeeSalary() {
        return employeeSalary;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(String employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }
    public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }
    public void setEmployeeSalary(double employeeSalary) {
        this.employeeSalary = employeeSalary;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Emp [employeeId=" + employeeId + ", employeeName="
                + employeeName + ", employeeSalary=" + employeeSalary + "]";
    }


}
```

This is a sample class. User will enter name of the class. According to user input i want to find the getter and setter methods and its details of the class. For this purpose i am using below code. But it is not showing gettes and setters of  employeeId,employeeName, employeeSalary.

```
BeanInfo info; 
info = Introspector.getBeanInfo(c.getClass()); 
MethodDescriptor[] md = info.getMethodDescriptors();            
for (MethodDescriptor methodDescriptor : md) {
    LOGGER.info("Method-"+methodDescriptor.getMethod().getName());          
}
```

I am trying to read methods of a class using the above code but it is not showing getters and setters of the declared fields.

Comment: Please show us an example of a class that you inspect with this code, and tell what parts you expect to be shown that do not get shown.

Comment: You should be looking at properties instead and check the read method.

Comment: I tested your code and it worked fine. How did you declare `c` ?

Comment: Your code looks fine, except for that we can't see what is "c". Is this maybe a class instead of an object of type Emp?

Answer (score 0):

I thing you might require Field class.
A Field class provides information about, and dynamic access to, a single field of a class or an interface. The reflected field may be a class (static) field or an instance field.
Use `Field[]`. 
Below is Package for it

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
```